# Подсчет нажатых кнопок ToggleButton в Android

Tags: java, android

Есть несколько кнопок на экране, нужно посчитать сколько в состоянии "ON". Как это лучше организовать?

Comment: А откуда берутся кнопки? Они статически расположены в layout или динамически создаются?

Comment: Они расположены на экране. При нажатии на кнопку (обычный acceptButton) подсчитать "включенные", или нажатые, - в проекте я менял дизайн, и они выглядят как нажатые. Если On, то добавляем 1, иначе 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```
private int getCountOfCheckedButtons(Context cntxt) {
    ToggleButton[] buttons = {
        (ToggleButton) cntxt.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1),
        (ToggleButton) cntxt.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2),
        (ToggleButton) cntxt.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3)
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (ToggleButton tb : buttons) {
        if (tb.getChecked()) i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за идею. Докодил до того что мне требуется.

Answer (score 3):

А что если просто добавить один слушатель для всех кнопок? Если при изменении состояния она стала активной то +1, а если неактивной то -1